# How to parse .txt file with both commas and new lines

Tags: java, android

I need to separate the names from the numbers separated with commas in the text file and add them into separate ArrayLists. I have a method for adding each new line into a single ArrayList. Here is that code.

```
File file = new File(mPath);

    if (file.exists()){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        try{
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;
            while( (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                allNames.add(line);
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return allNames;
    }
```

[TEXT FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7TxH.png)

I am new to Java so please do not discriminate!!

Comment: please add your text file as text, not as screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just use `String#split` here:

```
while( (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    allNames.add(line.split(", ")[0]);
}
```

This assumes that your text file has data of the form:

```
Hector, 1104
Johnny, 4302
Chano, 1123
```

In this case, you just want to capture everything before the first comma on each line.

**Edit:**

If you want to capture the numbers, use:

```
Integer.parseInt(line.split(",\\s+")[1])
```

Comment: So the allNames.add(line.split(",")[0]); will give me simply the names, correct? To add the numbers should I replace [0] with [1]??

Comment: @Hector you should try